# How to get event of change value on textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, recaptcha

I have some problem to get value change event on textarea.

I`m working on reCAPTCHA, in client side I have textarea where Google lib injects token and i cant take that textarea change event.

Here is the code in question:

```js
var el = $("#dod");
el.on("change", function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});


$("#bb").click(function() {
  $("#dod").val('other event value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <textarea id="dod"></textarea>
</div>

<button id="bb">other event</button>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ovosg22g/1/

I can take event of typical change of textarea value (when im typing or paste text into my element) but when other 'action' changes my element value event doesn`t fire.

Can you explain why it is happening? And tell me what i have to do to catch that event?

One more i need that for form validation, i want enable submit button only when captcha is correct (in this case when google lib inject token to textarea)

Comment: Could you explain more your problem and which is the event you want to catch ? And about enabling the button only when captcha is correct: this is the onchange event bound to the input in which the user types the captcha.

Comment: If you're programmatically changing the value of the textarea, you need to trigger the change event manually (which, given your example, would be `$("#dod").val('other event value').change()`)

Comment: @Fourat the problem is i dont know what that event is... I dont want enable my submit button on typing on captcha input - becouse that event will fire on any typing...

Comment: @billyonecan  yes, it would work, but how to add that trigger on event that is fireing somewhere in Googles lib? 
google lib: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

Comment: @Tomasz in this case explain what do you want to do exactly, maybe give us an example online

Comment: @Fourat i want catch event of change value, but in this case that event is not from my code. Everything would be good if that lib would trigger change() event like said billyonecan. I know how i could do this if i would acces to that code. My question is how to do it without acces, from my javascript. 
I done it (i validate my form) but my solution is "dirty", im validate form in loop ;) i know, no comment ;) Now question is how to do it better ;-)

Comment: @Tomasz could you make a fiddle of your real problem (not like the one above) ? Besides if the lib you're using (Google recaptcha I assume) is returning an object you can explore that object (console.log) and find the DOM element associated then trigger the event yourself.